# How to get current year in Android (min API version 15)

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin

I am building a simple age calculator application using Kotlin.

```
public fun calculateage(view: View){
    val dob: String = etbirth.text.toString()
    val currentyear = calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.Year)
    val age = currentyear - dob.toInt()
    tvage.setText("$age")
}
```

This method is not available in API level 15, requiring API level 24 minimum.

So how can I get the current year?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String currentyear = sdf.format(new Date());`

Comment: Calendar class is available from API 1. Which exactly method requires API 24?

Comment: Also why is the question tagged with `java` while it is in `kotlin`?

Comment: jyoti jk---->thank you its working

Comment: Vladyslav mantviienko--->this method requires apli level 24 or above

Comment: Vladyslav mantviienko--->it is tagged in java because it uses java.util.* for using SimpleDateFormat

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 5):

```
val year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

I tested this code, it works well even the min api level is 15.

[image]

Is this the picture you want?

Comment: L.swifter--> can u please share the screenshot

Comment: L.swifter-->thank you so much.But this is not working for me .

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.bp.Year.parse(          // Parse a string into a `Year` object. Using the back-port of *java.time* classes found in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, further adapted for earlier Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.
    "1961"                           // String input representing a year.
)
.until(                              // Calculate elapsed time.
    Year.now(                        // Get the current date’s year as a `Year` object rather than a mere integer number.
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )  // Get the current year as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (time zone). For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.
    ) ,
    ChronoUnit.YEARS                 // Specify the granularity of the elapsed time using `ChronoUnit` enum.
)                                    // Return a `long`.
```

> 57

## `Year`

> How to get current year in Android (min API version 15)

There’s a class for that!

[`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) shown in Java syntax (I don’t know Kotlin, yet)

```
Year.now()
```

Better to specify explicitly the desired/expected time zone rather than rely implicitly on your JVM’s current default time zone.

```
Year.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Lisbon" ) 
)
```

Pass this `Year` object around your code rather than mere integer numbers. This gives you [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and makes your code more self-documenting. When you do need a number, call [`Year.getValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#getValue()).

```
Year y = Year.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;
int yearNumber = y.getValue() ;
```

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Avoid `Calendar`, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` like the Plague.

For Java 6 & 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTenABP* project.

## Age

To calculate the age, parse your string input.

```
String input = "1961" ;
Year birthYear = Year.parse( input ) ;
```

Do the math. Specify a `TemporalUnit` (`ChronoUnit`) for the granularity of result.

```
Year now = Year.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;  // 2018 today.
long years = birthYear.until( now , ChronoUnit.YEARS ) ;
```

> 57

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

```
public fun calculateage(view: View){
        val dob: String = etbirth.text.toString()
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
        val currentyear1: String = sdf.format(Date()).toString()
     //   val currentyear = Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val age = currentyear1.toInt() - dob.toInt()
        tvage.setText("$age")
    }
```

> Thank you everyone for trying. thank you jyoti for your answer, this code is working perfectly.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).